# new caption type in captionof

Tags: captions, algorithm2e

`\captionof` command from caption package allows caption for various floats. However we cannot use it to typeset an algorithm caption like: `\captionof{Algorithm}{<Caption text>}`. I tried the following without success.

```
\setcaptiontype{Algorithm}
\captionsetup{options=algorithm}
\captionof{Algorithm}{My caption}
```

So my question is, can we define a new type to be used in `\captionof` command? If so how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *type* is different from what is typically used in the *naming*. In that regard, the `algorithm` environment typically use `Algorithm` as its name. [`algorithm2e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e) is slightly different though; it uses `algocf` as the type, so you need to use

```
\captionof{algocf}{<caption of algorithm>}
```

Make sure the `\captionof` macro is used inside an environment (or group).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm2e,caption}
\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
  \caption{My algorithm}
\end{algorithm}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
  \captionof{algocf}{My algorithm}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I tried this and it generates only the caption without the "type". I get the caption as follows. " : My algorithm ". Instead I wanted "Algorithm 1: My algorithm"

Comment: @okkhoy: You should mention that you're using [`algorithm2e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e)... That makes a difference.

Comment: Thanks @Werner, sorry that I missed an important piece of information. My bad.

Answer (score 2):

As to creating a new type, use \newfloat (or just \newcounter).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\newfloat{Algorithm}{htbp}{loa}
\begin{document}
\captionof{Algorithm}{test}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I used `\newfloat` and it worked! However, if you have an idea could you please explain why the default `algorithm` from `algorithm2e` package was not picked up?

Comment: The packaged where the algorithm environment was defined wasn't loaded.