# LaTeX: Individualized figure names in List of Figures

Tags: table-of-contents, captions, tocloft

sorry if this has been resolved elsewhere but I cannot find the solution and I'm not very LaTeX-savvy

Currently I have some "Figures" in my document with the unique label "Movie" (since they are captions for videos included separate from the document), and essentially I want these unique labels to appear as such in the List of Figures (obtained with `\listoffigures`). The way I am doing this is using `\captionsetup` from the `caption` package as follows:

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \captionsetup{name={Movie}}
    \caption{This is just the caption for a video included separately}
    \label{movie1}
\end{figure}
```

Of course, I also have some actual figures throughout my document with the standard label "Figure" as per the `\figurename` command, e.g.:

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics{myfigure.png}
    \caption{This is an example of one of many standardly labelled figures throughout the document}
    \label{figure1}
\end{figure}
```

In the List of Figures, I would like for it to appear something like:

> Movie 1: This is just the caption for a video included separately
>
> Figure 1: This is an example of one of many standardly labelled figures throughout the document

Using the `tocloft` package, I did manage to add the word "Figure" before the figure number and caption:

```
\renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{\bfseries \color{seccolor}\figurename\ }
\settowidth{\cftfignumwidth}{Figure 00.0000}
\listoffigures
```

However, unsurprisingly, this does not give me the desired result with regard to the "Movie" label, i.e., I get:

> Figure 1: This is just the caption for a video included separately
>
> Figure 1: This is an example of one of many standardly labelled figures throughout the document

(Note: I am resetting the Figure numbering hence the duplicate numbering)
(Also note: the `\settowidth{\cftfignumwidth}{Figure 00.0000}` command was something I found to fix the spacing, since without it the word "Figure" would overlap with the figure number)

Thanks so much in advance if anyone can offer some guidance!

Comment: don't use `figure` floats, use a `movie` float defined with `float` package, which will have its own counter and own list

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246131/new-caption-type-in-captionof for example.